# SQL code error in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi I am getting an error when trying to run:

> "ArgumentException was unhandled by usercode, Column 'ID' does not belong to the table."

The line of code that is generating this error is a MSSQL statement that I can run in SQL Server Management Studio with no error.

```
getType.SQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@listingid", tblListing.Rows[0]["ID"]);
```

The table does contain an ID Column.

Comment: can you show your query ?or sp

Comment: debug it, open the DataTable visualizer, figure out what your column name actually is

Comment: What is `tblListing`? Smells like a `DataTable`. Did you debug your code and check it _really_ has a column called `ID`?

Comment: first hard code your value and try .

Comment: If you provide more context it's more likely that you get high quality help. Eg. you could provide the actual column names of tblListing (which I expect doing in itself would provide the answer for you)

Comment: You might also want to take a peek at this article once you resolve your problem. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL statement is not the problem (you are able to execute it in SQL manager) and neither is it the call to `AddWithValue` because that won't throw an ArgumentException based on the cause in mentioned in the exception message. So it must be something else. That leaves a constant and an expression using the string `"ID"`as the argument for the parameter `ColumnName`

```
tblListing.Rows[0]["ID"]
```

The documentation for the index has the following documentation for when it will throw an ArgumentException

> The column specified by columnName cannot be found.

So your error is in that expression. The DataTable `tblListing` has no column named "ID"